# How do I get the current bandwidth speed of an interface from the terminal?

Tags: monitoring, bandwidth

I want to get the current Bandwidth of an interface say "eth0" from the terminal. It better be as simple as possible. Say 
        up 10 dn 30.
Instead of giving out a lot of text like "vnstat" does.

Edit: I need this for a command line program for auto-monitoring, not to view it manually.

Comment: you could try `iftop`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several tools that can do this.

#### Bmon

One that should be in most repositories for various distros is [`bmon`](http://www.carisma.slowglass.com/~tgr/bmon/).

[image: ss of bmon]

It can be run in a condensed view too.

[image: ss of bmon small]

If you're looking for something else I'd suggest taking a look at this Linuxaria article titled: [Monitor your bandwidth from the Linux shell](http://linuxaria.com/article/monitor-your-bandwidth-from-the-linux-shell). It also mentions [nload](http://www.roland-riegel.de/nload/) as well as [speedometer](http://excess.org/speedometer/).

#### Nload

[image: ss of nload]

#### Speedometer

[image: ss of speedometer]

#### Ibmonitor

If you're looking for something more basic then you could also give [ibmonitor](http://ibmonitor.sourceforge.net/) a go. Though basic it has most of the features one would expect when monitoring bandwidth.

[image: ss of ibmonitor]

Comment: And don't forget [**iftop**](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/).

Comment: @n.st - familiar with it, but didn't mention it since he wanted bandwidth methods, and  that shows per process, similar to `top`.

Comment: It does display the total bandwidth too, but I'll agree that it's probably less than ideal for automatic evaluation by a script like the OP intends to.

Comment: @n.st - yeah that's why I left it out, but I do use it regularly for finding mis-behaving network users 8-)

Answer (score -4):

You can also use [Linux process explorer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/procexp/). It can monitor bandwidth usage per process.

Comment: The question asked for a command-line program.